# Switching between arrays via a dropdown takes considerable amount. How do i reduce it ?? Angularjs ,IvhTreeview

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, watch, digest

I have fetched two arrays via rest-angular requests once the page is loaded. Later i use an angular module - ivh-tree view to display them. Both the arrays differ by 10^3 elements.
Issue: Switching between them via a dropdown takes considerable amount. How do i reduce it ??

Comment: Please include a code sample and a concise description of the problem, in this case, are you saying that switching takes a long time?  Or your solution requires too much code?

Comment: @stolli the code isn't much. Just that one of the arrays is a child of the other one and differ by 10^3 children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe any solution will require modifying `ivh-treeview` to be more efficient itself.

From a quick glance at the source for `ivh-treeview` it looks like it always renders the entire tree and toggles visibility as nodes are expanded and collapsed.

If you modified the directives to initially only render the already expanded nodes, and render-on-demand, then it should improve performance quite a bit as you'll only be rendering what you actually need.

Also note that `ivh-treeview` has a ton of nested repeaters without ever specifying `track by` (as a generic control it can't necessarily). If you change the requirements to provide an id field for each tree node, then you can add `track by` to the repeaters which has a positive impact on performance (but less than lazy loading).

Also note that as a large recursive structure of nested repeaters, performance can likely be improved by converting the data to a flat list with depth identifiers, and then rendering the whole tree as an individual list with css to control depth. This loses the semantic benefit of nested nodes, but likely has a positive impact on performance. It also would complicate many parts of the tree as you lose the benefit of the nested structures and almost automatic expansion and collapsing.